# Error : Please add realm to App.Config before running this sample (quick book PHP SDK)

Tags: quickbooks

I am using "PHP v3 SDK for QBO". I edited customer_query.php in the _sample folder & changed

```
RealmID (**Company id given**), AccessToken,AccessTokenSecret,ConsumerKey,ConsumerSecret
```

( These value I got when I did Test Connect to App). But I am getting the error `Please add realm to App.Config before running this sample`. Even though i had given the company id I am getting this error.

This is my code:

```
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Core/ServiceContext.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'DataService/DataService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'PlatformService/PlatformService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Utility/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php');

//Specify QBO or QBD
$serviceType = IntuitServicesType::QBO;
// Get App Config
$realmId = ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('55555555'); // **Company id given**
if (!$realmId)
    exit("**Please add realm to App.Config before running this sample**.\n"); // ***My code stop here***

// Prep Service Context
$requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('AccessToken'),
                                              ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('AccessTokenSecret'),
ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('ConsumerKey'),
ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('ConsumerSecret')); // **Actual key given**

$serviceContext = new ServiceContext($realmId, $serviceType, $requestValidator);
if (!$serviceContext)
    exit("Problem while initializing ServiceContext.\n");

// Prep Data Services
$dataService = new DataService($serviceContext);
if (!$dataService)
    exit("Problem while initializing DataService.\n");

// Run a query
$entities = $dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Customer");

// Echo some formatted output
$i = 0;
foreach($entities as $oneCustomer)
{
    echo "Customer[$i] GivenName: {$oneCustomer->GivenName} (Created at {$oneCustomer->MetaData->CreateTime})\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I guess, in App.config values are stored in key-value pairs. Are you sure for relam, key is '55555555' [ Ref - ConfigurationManager::AppSettings('55555555')] ? You can try to hard code the relamId in the relamId variable. Thanks

Comment: Manas, Where we can can set relamid & other token key in App.config. where is app.config in our php sdk v3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following link.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0210_ipp_php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

Instead of reading values from config files, you can hardcode values in the following code snippet.

```
$accessToken = '';
$accessTokenSecret = '';
$consumerKey = '';
$consumerSecret = '';

$requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(
$accessToken, $accessTokenSecret, $consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

$realmId = '';

$serviceType= IntuitServicesType::QBO;

$serviceContext = new ServiceContext($realmId, $serviceType, $requestValidator);

$dataService = new DataService($serviceContext);
```

It should work.

Comment: Each Time when we connect to Quickbook, The AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret are changing. But In the _sample code provieded by PHP v3 SDK for QBO, we need to hardcode the AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret key. Each time this values are changing, In Code we need to change these key otherwise code will not produce any result. Any permanent solution for this?

Comment: AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret get expired after 6 months. It can't be changed before that. In standalone code also you don't need to change anything. Can you please share the response XML which shows any error. As mentioned in the following doc, please configure the devkit logger to grab the raw request and response XMLs. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0210_ipp_php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3/0002_configuration
Thanks

Comment: Manas, thanks for the quick reply. Now My code is working fine. I am a beginner in quickbook & my doubt is about  getting these keys (Access Token,Access Token Secret).In my online application, I clicked  Test connect to app (OAuth). After connecting to my test app, I clicked the link  "App Menu API Test". In this page I got all keys(Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Access Token Secret). Are you saying, user do not want to click & connect again. If so, there will no need to change the these keys(Access Token,Access Token Secret) in customer fecthing file in PHP SDK Sample.

Comment: You can have a look at this link which describes the app user flow - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0005_introduction_to_quickbooksapi/0010_your_app_users_experience
The end user go through 3 legged OAuth flow and after that your app stores those OAuth tokens. Next time when the end user logs in then you retrieves the OAuth tokens from your DB and call QB endpoints on top of his cloud data. After 6 months those tokens get expired. Till then you're good to go with the existing tokens.

Comment: Manas, How can I store app token in my APP database. I can store those keys manually in my database. In the link provied by you saying you can connect to quickbook form my app. how can we store these keys dynamically in my database. will we get a any response back. Please give me a detailed answer....

Comment: Oauth tokens are nothing but 4 strings here. If your qts is how to persist 4 strings in database, then I would suggest you to google a bit to know how to interact with DB. Thanks

Comment: Manas, do you know how to add & upadte the invoice against a customer in code wise. I did not find any example in the sample folder of PHP v3 SDK  for QBO. Please help me how can i add or upadte an invoice (Using v3 SDK for QBO).

Comment: @Shino, there is no ready code examples. You can go through the link which I've shared before - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0210_ipp_php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis. Instead of Customer, you can create an invoice object and populate data. After that it is same as customer. There(Invoice) must be a method like setCustomerRef(ReferenceType).. pass the customerRef(customerId) and construct the invoice object.